# What does "an $n$-qubit array can represent $2^n$ possible array elements" mean?

Tags: quantum-state

I read "...an $n$ qubit array can represent $2^n$ possible array elements.." on [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1383/what-makes-quantum-computers-so-good-at-computing-prime-factors) post. A classical $n$-bit array can represent $2^n$ possible array elements as well, so I'm confused about the difference. Does it mean that the $2^n$ possibilities represented by the $n$-qubit array are represented at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

> Now here is where it gets deep an  Qubit Array can represent $2^$ possible array elements (consult anywhere online for an explanation of that or drop a comment).
>
> And similarly an  Qubit quantum operator can act on that entire $2^$ quantum space, and produce an answer that we can interpret.

It's probably not too clear here, but I think the OP meant, an $n$ qubit array can represent any state that is a linear combination of $2^n$ basis states.

So, a classical array of 1 bit could represent any state 0 or 1 ($2^1$ possibilities), but a single qubit could be in any state $\alpha |0\rangle + \beta |1\rangle $ where $|\alpha|^2 + |\beta|^2 = 1$, so an infinite number of possibilities made from a basis of $2^n$ states.