# What is the reason for the exponential speed-up of quantum computers?

Tags: quantum-advantage

In quantum computers the following two effects should be seen:

1. If an operator acts on an arbitrary qubit $Q_n$ of a quantum system $S$ consisting of several qubits than we get a new quantum system $S'$ where the amplitudes of all qubits have changed.
2. If an operator acts on one qubit of a quantum system $T$ consisting of two entangled QuBits than both qubits are affected.

So which one of these is the reason for the exponential speed-up expected from quantum computers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What exactly makes quantum computers faster than classical computers?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6198/what-exactly-makes-quantum-computers-faster-than-classical-computers). See also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1383/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2444/55, https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1584/55 and links therein